# Sacar el random para guardar una imagen

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, json

Este código lo saqué por Internet, pero me guarda las imágenes con un número random y lo qué yo quiero es qué me guarde los nombres originales de las imágenes que guardo, no quiero que me lo codifique.

Este es el codigo para guardar

```
<?php

//  Conexión con MySQL
require_once('dbConnection.php');

// Upload multiple image in Database using PHP MYSQL
if (!empty($_FILES['multipleFile']['name'])) {
    $multiplefile = $_FILES['multipleFile']['name'];
    foreach ($multiplefile as $name => $value) {
        $allowImg = array('png','jpeg','jpg','gif');   
        $fileExnt = explode('.', $multiplefile[$name]);
        $fileTmp = $_FILES['multipleFile']['tmp_name'][$name];
        $newFile = rand(). '.'. $fileExnt[1];
        $target_dir = 'uploads/'.$newFile; 
        if (in_array($fileExnt[1], $allowImg)) {
            if ($_FILES['multipleFile']['size'][$name] > 0 && 
                $_FILES['multipleFile']['error'][$name]== 0) {
                if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $target_dir)) {
                    $query  = "INSERT INTO table_images (images,nombre) 
                        VALUES('$newFile','$newFile ')";
                    mysqli_query($con, $query);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
//  Conexión con MySQL
require_once('dbConnection.php');

// Upload multiple image in Database using PHP MYSQL
if (!empty($_FILES['multipleFile']['name'])) {
    $multiplefile = $_FILES['multipleFile']['name'];
    foreach ($multiplefile as $name => $value) {
        $allowImg = array('png','jpeg','jpg','gif');   
        $fileExnt = explode('.', $value);
        $fileTmp = $_FILES['multipleFile']['tmp_name'][$name];
        $target_dir = 'uploads/'.$value; 
        if (in_array($fileExnt[1], $allowImg)) {
            if ($_FILES['multipleFile']['size'][$name] > 0 && 
                $_FILES['multipleFile']['error'][$name]== 0) {
                if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $target_dir)) {
                    $query  = "INSERT INTO table_images (images,nombre) 
                        VALUES('$value','$value')";
                    mysqli_query($con, $query);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Cambios realizados:

- Ese código que has recogido de internet hace esto en un punto determinado:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $target_dir)) {
```

y sabiendo que la función [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php) usa dos parámetros, que son **nombre_de_archivo** y **destino**, podemos deducir que `$target_dir` contiene el nombre de archivo que se va a grabar en disco.

Así pues, localizamos donde se define esa variable y la encontramos en esta línea:

```
$target_dir = 'uploads/'.$newFile;
```

con lo cual deducimos que el nombre de archivo está compuesto de una carpeta destino, llamada **uploads/**, al cual le concatenamos el valor de la variable *$newFile*, por lo tanto ahora vamos a buscar donde se define el valor de esa variable *$newFile*.

Y la encontramos en esta línea:

```
$newFile = rand(). '.'. $fileExnt[1];
```

donde, si miramos lo que hace la función [rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rand.php) vemos que genera un número aleatorio, que es justamente lo que queremos cambiar.

Por lo tanto vamos a realizar el cambio justo aquí, poniendo esto en su lugar:

```
$target_dir = 'uploads/'.$value;
```

¿y que es `$value`?  Buena pregunta! :-D  Vamos a buscarlo a ver... sí, lo encontramos aquí:

```
foreach ($multiplefile as $name => $value) {
```

es decir, parece el valor de cada elemento del array $multiplefile, que descomponemos en **$name** y **$value**. mmmm... ¿pero que narices es `$multiplefile`?  ¿Porque se llama así?  ¿Existe un dios?

Sí, lo se, son las típicas preguntas existenciales que siempre nos hacemos... pero centremonos por un momento y busquemos en el código lo que es $multiplefile, y lo encontramos aquí:

```
$multiplefile = $_FILES['multipleFile']['name'];
```

Vaaale... ya vemos donde está definido, y ahora nos interesa saber que es $_FILES, pues ni idea ahora mismo, por lo tanto lo buscamos de nuevo en el manual de PHP y lo encontramos, como debe ser, en su [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files.php), donde dice claramente:

> Un array asociativo de elementos subidos al script en curso a través
> del método POST.

Bueno, pues vale, según se entiende, es un array, perooo... (siempre hay un *pero*)... ¿siempre tiene una clave llamada `multipleFile`? mmmm.... pues va a ser que no, porque segun pone de nuevo en [la documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php) parece ser el valor del atributo **name=** del input tipo `file` que aparece en el formulario (que no está en la pregunta, pero lo deducimos gracias a esto).

Vale, ya sabemos lo que es la primera clave del array $_FILES denominada `multipleFile`... y ahora queremos saber que es la segunda clave de ese array multidimensional denominada `name` y nos hacemos la misma pregunta... ¿siempre va a haber una clave `name` en el array $_FILES?... y en este caso resulta que la respuesta es que **sí**, tal como aparece en [su documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php) de nuevo, donde ademas vemos que hay otras claves fijas como `type`, `size`, `tmp_name` y `error`.

Bueno, misterios aclarados pues. Ahora, sabiendo todo eso podemos deducir que la clave `name` de `$_FILES['multipleFile']` (o sea, `$_FILES['multipleFile']['name']`, contiene el nombre del archivo subido. Pero resulta que en este caso parece que no es un registro único, sino un array de nombres, porque seguramente, aunque no aparece en la pregunta, el `<input type="file">` contiene el atributo `multiple`, que permite la subida de varios archivos a la vez.

(Nota: tranquilos, que ya estamos llegando a lo que es `$value`)

Y es por eso, que ese código que *estaba por la red* intenta recorrer dicho array de este modo:

```
foreach ($multiplefile as $name => $value) {
```

que, después de haber aprendido todo lo anterior, nos podemos dar cuenta que a partir de aquí, la variable $name **no** contiene un nombre, sino un número de índice de la matriz, y que el autor de ese código encontrado por la red no se molestó demasiado en poner unos nombres menos confusos al hacer eso.

Siguiendo la misma lógica, nos damos cuenta que $value **sí** que contiene el nombre del archivo subido!!!  Pues vaya, ya les vale... en fin.. seguimos...

Ahora pues, ya empezamos a entender esta línea que aparece en la respuesta:

```
$target_dir = 'uploads/'.$value;
```

pues ahora entendemos que, al ser `$value` el nombre del archivo subido, y al ser `$target_dir` el nombre (con la ruta) del archivo destino que vamos a usar en la línea del **move_uploaded_file()**, todo nos cuadra y ya hemos solucionado el problema **1** que era subirlo con su nombre real.

Pero la cosa no termina aquí, pues hay que vigilar los efectos colaterales de ese cambio, y nos dedicamos a buscar la ya eliminada variable `$newFile` en el resto del código, por si acaso, y pam, la encontramos en esta línea:

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO table_images (images,nombre) 
                        VALUES('$newFile','$newFile ')";
```

y como ya no existe, volvemos a cambiarla por $value en este caso, quedando la consulta de este modo:

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO table_images (images,nombre) 
                        VALUES('$value','$value')";
```

para que no de error la consulta... la cual, si nos fijamos bien, duplica el valor en dos columnas del mismo registro, lo cual es asombrosamente inutil, pero bueno, es un código que está en Internet y gratis!!  Tampoco podemos pedir peras al olmo que dicen...

Obviando lo de la consulta, y siguiendo el repaso al código, nos encontramos con esto también, que nos causa cierta confusión de nuevo:

```
$fileExnt = explode('.', $multiplefile[$name]);
```

pues, a ver si lo entendemos... primero vamos a ponernos en contexto... esa línea aparece dentro de este bucle de nuevo:

```
foreach ($multiplefile as $name => $value) {
```

y dentro del bucle sale la otra línea que invoca a `$multiplefile[$name]`... que curiosamente **ya estamos recorriendo y que nos divide cada registro en `$name` (el índice del array) y `$value` (el valor que se corresponde con el nombre del archivo subido)**... por lo tanto... si ya tenemos a **`$value`**... ¿porque intentamos conseguir ese valor llamándolo por su índice con `$multiplefile[$name]`???  No tiene mucho sentido desaprovechar a `$value` de esta manera, además *se puede enfadar sintiéndose totalmente inutil*, pues en el código encontrado en *Internet* **no se usa para nada** y el autor de ese fantástico código gratuito lo obvió totalmente como si no sirviera para nada.

En fin, pero aquí, que somos muy listos, y ya hemos aprendido todo lo anterior, decidimos usarlo de nuevo sustituyendo a `$multiplefile[$name]` por `$value` en esta línea:

```
$fileExnt = explode('.', $value);
```

Y con esto ya nos quedamos más tranquilos y damos por finalizada la primera revisión del código, el cual seguramente tiene más cosas a optimizar, refactorizar y mejorar, pero como ya funciona da igual, ¿para qué?  Ahora ya podemos copiar y pegar el código en nuestro proyecto e irnos a dormir felices sin haber aprendido nada, pues **nadie** habrá leído hasta aquí ni le importa nada la explicación de estos cambios, pues es un rollo de narices que a un pirao le ha dado por escribir cuando nos importa un bledo entenderlo xD

PD: Lo he hecho de este modo porque el propósito de este sitio es compartir conocimiento y **aprender** unos de otros, pero dado el primer comentario del OP en esta pregunta, **agradeciéndomelo sin esperar mi explicación final**, me ha dado que pensar que ya se ha ido contento habiendo copiado la respuesta y sin entender lo que habia pasado, y ya va siendo hora que los que pregunten de este modo se lo curren un poco y si no atienden en clase o no miran la documentación, al menos que se empapen de información en las respuestas hasta la saciedad :-)

Comment: perfecto...funciono....TE AGRADEZCO POR TU TIEMPO y gracias tambien a los qué respondieron...GRACIAS

Comment: Acabo de agregar la explicación, por si te sirve para algo :-)

Comment: una explicación ferpecta!

Comment: obviamente me interesa.....gracias por tu tiempo....SALUDOS

Comment: masterguru   tu explicacion es fantastica y nos da aun mas conocimiento en este tema de programacion, reitero nuevamente GRACIAS POR TU TIEMPO..

Comment: masterguru   tu explicacion es fantastica y nos da aun mas conocimiento en este tema de programacion, reitero nuevamente GRACIAS POR TU TIEMPO..

Answer (score 1):

En esta linea es donde crea el nombre random:

```
$newFile = rand(). '.'. $fileExnt[1];
```

Modificala según quieras, por ejemplo:

```
$newFile = $multiplefile[$name];
```

Comment: Hola..gracias por contestar....me guarda el nombre bien pero al final me pone .array en la base me guarda asi: Club Estudiantil.jpg.Array

Comment: Disculpa, escribí el código al vuelo y no me di cuenta de que fileExnt es un array. He editado el código, ahora te debería funcionar bien.

Comment: @psauleda Perdona que te corrija, tu respuesta está muy bien y es increiblemente más corta que la mía :-D  pero he de señalarte un pequeño fallo, pues das por supuesto que `explode` despieza el valor de `$multiplefile[$name]`, lo cual no es así, simplemente divide una cadena con el patrón que le pasamos (en este caso un punto) **pero** los pone en un array, en este caso, en otra variable llamada `$fileExnt`, _dejando intacta_ la original `$multiplefile[$name]`.  Por lo tanto, una posible respuesta correcta sería `$newFile = $multiplefile[$name];` y otra sería `$newFile = $value;`.

Comment: @psauleda Si lo corriges te voto positivamente y borro estos comentarios :-)

Comment: Tenéis razón, lo estaba liando más de la cuenta. Lo modifico. Respecto a los comentarios, yo creo que incluso es más provechoso dejarlos, pues ponen de relieve puntos en los que es fácil equivocarse. Aunque igual una vez corregido no tiene mucho sentido. Lo que tu veas. Un placer trabajar en este problemilla con vosotros!!!

Comment: jeje, bueno, pues vamos a dejarlos... si alguien quiere ver lo que ha pasado siempre está el historial de cambios al cual puedes acceder pulsando sobre el enlace que aparece debajo de la pregunta, donde pone eso de "editada hace xxx minutos/horas/dias".  Gracias por corregirlo! Saludos